# React Native: how to apply shadow and borderRadius to a View?

Tags: react-native, shadow

Is there a way to apply a `shadow` AND a `borderRadius` to a `View` component, with the shadow following the rounded corners ?

Currently you have to set `overflow: 'hidden'` for `borderRadius` to work, but doing so removes the shadows.

It apparently is [an old and known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/449) in React Native, likely not going to be fixed in the near future. A workaround was proposed in this issue, of superposing two Views but no code sample was given.

Can anybody give a code example of this proposed solution ? Will it follow the rounded corners (I doubt it) ?

Is there a package with some [native binding voodoo doing the trick](https://medium.com/swifty-tim/views-with-rounded-corners-and-shadows-c3adc0085182) ?

Is there another solution ?

I already tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215055/react-native-manipulate-view-to-apply-shadow-to-images-borderradius) but it did not work for a View, the borderRadius prop does not work and triggers a warning advising to nest it in a `style` prop.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can make use of [this tool](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/) to generate parameters to shadows for both android and iOS.

And the trick is to make two Views, one for shadow with transparent background, other for the Content itself, both of them with the same `borderRadius` so a basic card will look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

export default () => {

return (
 <View style={styles.cardShadow}>
  <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
    <Text> Card Content </Text>
  </View>
 </View>
)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
cardShadow: {
 borderRadius: 16,
 backgroundColor: 'transparent',
 shadowColor: '#000',
 shadowOffset: {
   width: 0,
   height: 1,
 },
 shadowOpacity: 0.22,
 shadowRadius: 2.22,
 elevation: 3,
},
cardContainer: {
 backgroundColor: '#fff',
 borderRadius: 16,
 overflow: 'hidden',
},
});
```

In essence this is what you need to make a View with shadow and rounded corners, you could add also some margin/padding and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to make a nice floating card.

Comment: just know that this answer although works perfectly, will now throw up tons of errors in newer versions of react since the wrapping view has a transparent background and rn is unable to calculate shadows efficiently apparently with a clear background

Answer (score 5):

Yeah this is what they meant by that:

```
const shadowsStyling = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 0
    }
}

<View styles={shadowsStyling}>
   <View styles={{width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 10, overflow: 'hidden'}} />
</View>
```

Comment: I appreciate people like you.